# where pmd gradle report generate for groovy

Tags: gradle, groovy, pmd

here is configuration and it show build successful but not generate report. Any help would be appreciated.

```
apply plugin: 'pmd'
    apply plugin: "findbugs"
    pmd(
      'net.sourceforge.pmd:pmd-core:5.2.1',
      'net.sourceforge.pmd:pmd-java:5.2.1',
      'net.sourceforge.pmd:pmd-groovy:5.2.1'
       )

    findbugs {
    //consoleOutput = true
    ignoreFailures = true
    toolVersion = "2.0.1"
    sourceSets = [sourceSets.main]
    reportsDir = file("build/reports/findbugs")
    effort = "max"
    }

    pmd {
    consoleOutput= true
    ignoreFailures = false
    // sourceSets = [sourceSets.main]
    reportsDir = file("build/reports/pmd")
    ruleSets = [
            "basic",
            "braces",
            "naming",
            "android",
            "clone"       
    ]
    }

   tasks.withType(FindBugs) {
    reports {
        xml.enabled = false
        html.enabled = true
    }
   }
   tasks.withType(Pmd){
     reports {
        xml.enabled false
        html.enabled true
    }
```

Here are result of my build

```
./gradlew build
    :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
    :compileGroovy UP-TO-DATE
    :processResources UP-TO-DATE
    :classes UP-TO-DATE
    :findMainClass
    :jar
    :bootRepackage
    :assemble
    :findbugsMain UP-TO-DATE
    :pmdMain UP-TO-DATE
    :pmdTest UP-TO-DATE
    :compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
    :compileTestGroovy UP-TO-DATE
    :processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
    :testClasses UP-TO-DATE
    :test UP-TO-DATE
    :check UP-TO-DATE
    :build
```

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 8.731 secs

Comment: This line in output `:pmdMain UP-TO-DATE` indicates that `pmdMain` task wasn't executed at all. Please try `./gradlew clean build`.

Comment: Oh Thanks but ./gradlew clean build also have similar output. now i am not sure if its executing pmd or not  ./gradlew clean build
:clean
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileGroovy
:processResources
:classes
:findMainClass
:jar
:bootRepackage
:assemble
:findbugsMain UP-TO-DATE
:pmdMain UP-TO-DATE
:pmdTest UP-TO-DATE
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileTestGroovy
:processTestResources
:testClasses
:test